# Template pass member function with args and return value as parameter c++

Tags: c++, function, templates

I would like to pass a templated function args for class and a method of that class to call. The method has arguments as well as a return value.

Here is what I have so far. I believe I'm getting a little tripped up on the templatized function syntax:

### bar.h

```
    class Bar {
     public:
       Bar();
       int FuncBar(int arg1);
    }
```

### foo.h

```
    template<typename A, int (A::*Method)()>
    int FuncTemplate(A* a, int bar_arg1) {
      ....
      return a->Method(bar_arg1)
    }


    class Foo { 
     public:
       explicit Foo(Bar* bar);

     private:
       void FuncFoo();
       Bar* bar_;
    }
```

#### foo.cc

```
    Foo::Foo(Bar bar) : bar_(bar) {};
    void Foo::FuncFoo() {
      ...
      int bar_arg1 = 0;
      FuncTemplate<Bar, &(*bar_)::FuncBar>(bar_, bar_arg1);
    }
```

Comment: What's the error and where does it occurs?

Comment: `*a` is not a type. You want something like `decltype(*a)` or simply `&A::FuncBar`

Comment: In foo.cc, what is `a`?

Comment: appologies, a should be bar_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `int (A::*Method)(int)` as the function pointer type since the member function expects an `int` as an argument.

Also, the call to the member function needs to be `(a->*Method)(bar_arg1)`. The syntax for calling member function using a member function is not very intuitive.

```
template<typename A, int (A::*Method)(int)>
int FuncTemplate(A* a, int bar_arg1) {
  ....
  return (a->*Method)(bar_arg1)
}
```

Also, you need to use `&Bar::FuncBar` to get a pointer to the member function, not `&(*bar_)::FuncBar`.

```
void Foo::FuncFoo() {
   int bar_arg1 = 0;
   FuncTemplate<Bar, &Bar::FuncBar>(bar_, bar_arg1);
   //                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: Follow up: Is it possible to use templatized parameters the arguments to the method? Or otherwise not include them? E.g.

template<typename A, int (A::*Method)(B, C)>

Comment: @MattStokes, I didn't understand that question.

Comment: If I had a second function which I wanted to use this template with that had instead of an int argument a string. Could you templatize the argument type to Method:

template<typename A, int (A::*Method)(B)> OR template<typename A, int (A::*Method)(A)>

Comment: Yes, you can. Come up with a mcve and post it in another question if you can't make it work.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not compile. I get the following errors:

1) a->*Method expected unqualified-id 2) candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'Method'

Comment: Nice, alright I'll figure it out for my explicit case then. Thanks!